# Icon rendered with offset

Tags: flutter, dart

When I tried to use IconButtons, I noticed that they were rendered incorrectly - the icon itself was offset to the right bottom, while the clicking animation was perfectly fine. Now my question is: Is this issue related to my code or is it Flutter's fault?

This is the build method of the StatelessWidget the IconButtons are located in:

```
return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => {},
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.play_circle_outline,
              size: 50,
            ),
            color: Color(0xff3C6E71),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

This is how it looks when the button is clicked, the Icon itself is offset to the bottom right but the clicking animation is perfectly centered how it should be.

[image: Visualization of the problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably some issue with the widget `padding`, you can try adding a `padding` with the value zero:

```dart
return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => {},
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // set padding to zero
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.play_circle_outline,
              size: 50,
            ),
            color: Color(0xff3C6E71),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```